# Why does the save command fail when called from within a listener callback function?

Tags: matlab, save, runtime-error

I'm trying to call MATLAB's **save** function from inside a listener callback function to save some computed results to disk in a .mat file. My program has a GUI and is organized using a MVC pattern. When the user presses a button in the GUI, the button's callback for the button press calls a method on the Model class. That method in the Model class in turn issues an event notification:

```
notify(this, 'EstimateModelParametersRequest');
```

Back in the View, a listener was registered for that event when the GUI was first initialized:

```
addlistener(m, 'EstimateModelParametersRequest', ...
        @(o,e) OnEstimateModelParametersRequest(handles, e.Source));
```

So, when the use clicks the button, what ultimately happens is that a function in the View is listening for and handles the event:

```
function OnEstimateModelParametersRequest(handles, model)
     % There's some code here that calls methods of the Model class to compute results and then plots those results

     % After plotting the results, we want to save them to disk
     [filename, pathname] = uiputfile({'*.mat'}, 'File to save results in', 'results.mat');
     save(fullfile(pathname, filename), 'results', '-mat');
end
```

The problem that I keep running into is that the call to **save** routinely fails, giving the following error:

```
Warning: Error occurred while executing the listener callback for event
EstimateModelParametersRequest defined for class Model:
Error using save
Error closing file C:\myfilepath\myresults.mat.
The file may be corrupt.
```

My best guess as to what might be happening is that perhaps the function call to **save** is returning to the calling function before it has finished writing all of the data to disk, the calling function returns immediately after the call to **save** thus triggering deallocation of the local variables that were used within the **OnEstimateModelParametersRequest** function. Because there's a lot of data to be written to disk, ultimately deallocation and garbage collection of the local variable **results** happens before the save operation completes.

If that is indeed what is happening, then it would seem that the solution would be to somehow force **save** to flush the write cache or some such thing in order to ensure the data is persisted before the **OnEstimateModelParametersRequest** function exits. Is that indeed what's going on and, if so, how can I force the **save** operation to complete?

Comment: it's a long shot but did you try to save to another path other than C ? like d:\filepath\...?

Comment: also, this might help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18098-error-using-save-error-closing-file

Comment: Try doing `dbstop if warning; dbstop if all error` and then run your code. It should drop you in to the debugger where the error happens so you can have a look at it in that context. Also make sure your disk isn't full and that you have write permissions to that directory.